# Android studio does not start the application on the external device(application does not get installed)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am trying android studio for the first time.

I have connected external android device via USB (debugging device settings are done in android device). I click on run button with selection as USB device.

The Run console shows this

Waiting for device.

Target device: iball-3g_q1035-0123456789ABCDEF

Whereas my gradle console shows this

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.292 secs

But my application does not start on the device. Can somebody please let me know where i am doing mistake?(ps : application works perfectly on the eclipse)

Comment: When you say that it doesn't start on the device, do you mean that it doesn't install at all, or it does install but won't automatically launch?

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth thanks for the reply,yes it doesn't install at all.

Comment: Okay. I don't have a quick answer for you, but let's get some more information that might help out. What OS are you running? What version of Android Studio is it? What is the device you're trying to run on?

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth android studio version is 1.1.0, trying to run on device named as iBall slide, Android version on tab is 4.4.2